# I have string like [["Mayur","Mahesh","Meet"],[25,27,24]] how can i parse it so it look like List<List<String>> nameAgeList?

Tags: java, regex, collections, java-8, java-7

Please pardon me if my question is odd as I am novice in java.

I want something like

```
ArrayList nameLst = nameAgeList.get(0);
ArrayList ageLst = nameAgeList.get(1);
```

Please let me know if you want any other details.

Comment: Assuming there’s a `"` right after `Mayur`, this is JSON, so parse it as JSON.

Comment: No it is not typical json as it doen't have key like {"Name":"Mayur"}

Comment: are the names always surrounded by quote marks and are they allowed to contain string escape sequences? and if so which ones?

Comment: yes all names will always be surrounded by quote and there won't be any special character

Comment: It would be better to interpret it as a `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` in my opinion. And these two wrapped in an object to parse the string as JSON then.

Comment: I agree with Sebastian. This is JSON so why reinvent a json parser? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293555/how-do-you-represent-a-json-array-of-strings

Comment: Can anyone let me know why my question is downvoted?

Comment: @mangukiyamayur [This _is_ JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: I haven’t found the good original question yet, but this smells like a duplicate to me.

Comment: Looking for something like `(\[.*?\])\g`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Jackson's ObjectMapper` and parse it like a json:

```
String input = "[[\"Mayur\",\"Mahesh\",\"Meet\"],[25,27,24]]";
List<List<Object>> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, List.class);
List<String> nameLst = list.get(0).stream().map(i -> (String) i).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> ageLst = list.get(1).stream().map(i -> (Integer) i).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Would the second list be parsed as a `List<String>` successfully?

Comment: it will be parsed to Object, but if you want them as integer then you will need to type cast explicitly

Comment: better: use TypeFactory to avoid explicit casting https://stackoverflow.com/a/40630765/7098259

Answer (score 0):

you can write it in for
like that:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
String[][] stringArray = [["yourString"]["yourString"]];
for(String[] secondArray : stringArray){
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String string : secondArray){
        stringList.add(string);
    }
    finalList.add(stringList);
}
```

the finalList is your ans you can write this as method to use it in code easier. like that :

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parseArray(String[][] stringArray){
    ArrayList<ArrayList> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String[] secondArray : stringArray){
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String string : secondArray){
            stringList.add(string);
        }
        finalList.add(stringList);
    }
    return finalList;
}
```

hear you are.

Comment: better use maps in java